# "Automatic" transfer of an SQL Server table into an F# matrix

Tags: sql-server, f#, import, matrix

I have the following code that is doing importation from SQL to F# and translating the information into a matrix.

I have here an example of users having 4 criterias but if I want to add 2 more criterias for example (and the number of criterias may change) I will have to do it manually (in this code the dimension is not done automatically and the name of the columns have to be written).

This solution works but I have to check manually the evolutions in the SQL table and to change manually the name of the columns in my code which will soon be very painful. So my question is :

Do you see a way to have the dimensions of the SQL table automatically taken into account and more generally, do you have a way to do this importation without having to write manually the name of each column ("Criteria0_ID" etc. are the name of the Columns in SQL") ? Thks in advance !

```ml
type user = {
    Criteria0_ID :  int;
    Criteria1_ID : int;
    Criteria2_ID : int;
    Criteria3_ID : int}

// Extraction from SQL

module ReadSQl =

    let GetUsers = seq { 
        let connStr = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(DataSource="localhost\sqlexpress", IntegratedSecurity=true, InitialCatalog="TestExtractionF#")
        use cnn = new SqlConnection(connStr.ConnectionString)
        use cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM SyntheseTest", cnn)
        cnn.Open()

        use reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        while reader.Read() do
        yield {
               Criteria0_ID = unbox(reader.["Criteria0_ID"])
               Criteria1_ID = unbox(reader.["Criteria1_ID"])
               Criteria2_ID = unbox(reader.["Criteria2_ID"])
               Criteria3_ID = unbox(reader.["Criteria3_ID"])
               }
         }

// Sequence transformation

let UserBase = GetUsers |> Seq.toList

// Creating the matrix

let matrixUA =
    Matrix.ofList
        [ // Create list containing rows from the database
        for row in UserBase do
      // For each row, return list of columns (float values)
            yield [ float row.Criteria0_ID; 
                    float row.Criteria1_ID;
                    float row.Criteria2_ID;
                    float row.Criteria3_ID;
                                    ] ]

matrixUA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [FsSql](https://github.com/mausch/FsSql) you can write something like this:

```
let readMatrixUA() =
    let connStr = SqlConnectionStringBuilder(DataSource="localhost\sqlexpress", IntegratedSecurity=true, InitialCatalog="TestExtractionF#")
    use cnn = new SqlConnection(connStr.ConnectionString)
    cnn.Open()
    Sql.execReader (Sql.withConnection cnn) "select * from SyntheseTest" []
    |> Sql.map Sql.asNameValue
    |> Seq.map (Seq.map (snd >> Option.fromDBNull >> Option.getOrDefault >> float))
    |> Matrix.ofSeq
```

Comment: This could be a very good answer, I just have an error I do not understand : ExecuteReader needs an open and availabe Connection. The connection is actually closed. This error seem to refer to C:\prg\FsSql\FsSql\FsSql.fs:line 193 and C:\prg\FsSql\FsSql\FsSql.fs:line 203.

Comment: @katter75 : I forgot to open the connection. Edited my answer to fix that.

Comment: Yes thank you I had this corrected, now an new error is saying : The specified cast is not valid (the error seems to come from the execReader)

Comment: @katter75 : I don't know as what type the database tries to read fields. This code tries to read them directly as floats. You might want to try reading them as int first, then converting them to floats.

Comment: @katter75 : e.g. instead of `Seq.cast` do `Seq.cast<int> >> Seq.map float`

Comment: Just one more question : if in the SQL table I have "NULL" values (i.e. the user has not answered the question), can I retreat it to have zeros in my matrix ? (for the moment I have the same error "the specified cast is not valid" as soon as I have a "NULL" in SQL)

Answer (score 1):

In the current version of F#, you'll always need to define the `user` type yourself. You can do a few tricks to make the copying nicer. The easiest thing to do is to use the `?` operator to get the following syntax:

```
let (?) (reader:SqlDataReader) (name:string) : 'T =
  unbox (reader.[name])

 yield { Criteria1_ID = reader?Criteria1_ID
         Criteria2_ID = reader?Criteria2_ID 
         Criteria3_ID = reader?Criteria3_ID }
```

You can take it even further - if you open `Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection`, you can use `FSharpType.GetRecordFields` to get the names of the fields (using reflection) and do the copying dynamically - if you use this approach, you'll only need to change the record declaration. That's probably as far as you can get with the current version of F#.

However, F# 3.0 (coming in Visual Studio 11) contains a feature called *type provders* that essentially allows you to import the schema automatically. You can learn more from talks by Don Syme (see [for example this](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/PDC/PDC10/FT12)) and from the [MSDN (draft) documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156509%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).